# How to build with npm run start?

Tags: heroku, webpack

I'm using webpack and heroku.
When I push my web to heroku it will restart and do "npm run start".
What I want to do is doing "npm run start" with "npm run build" when I push my web to heroku

here's my pakage.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --hot --open --inline",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules",
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules&&node server.js"
  },
```

What I tried is this but, not working

```
 "start": "set NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules&&node server.js"
```

Comment: why it didn't work? what was the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update:

Maybe your scripts isnt working in heroku because, by default they are running linux and you are triyng to run the *"set"* command that belongs to windows. Try removing it form the script and let *cross-env* do all the rest of the work for you :)

## Previous response:

I know this isnt the best solution, but I hope it helps you:

If the problem is in the concatenation of commands to run,  you can install  ["npm-run-all"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) to your project and then you will be able yo run several scripts in secuential order.

In your case, you could set the scripts like this:

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --hot --open --inline",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules",
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules",
    "run-server": "node server.js",
    "build-sart-n-run": "run-s build start run-server"

  }
```

After that you can run ,either via [Heroku CLI using a procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) or using the tools that the web UI gives you when you login, the next command:

```
   $ node build-sart-n-run
```

sorry if my english inst very good :)